# duplicate symbol _jk_collectionClassLoadTimeInitialization in

Tags: xcode

2012-07-12 19:12:09.962 Tunecast[1982:907] (null)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Start by finding out where in your code it's defined.  One of the most common ways of making this happen is by defining a variable inside a .h file (instead of only declaring it) and then including/importing the .h more than once in your project.

Comment: 2012-07-12 19:12:09.962 Tunecast[1982:907] (null)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Comment: No idea.  My answer was for the question you originally asked, not what you edited it to say.